# Skype links in IE

Tags: internet-explorer, skype

They are ruining the page I'm making. Anyone know a way of turning them off?

It ends up making the text look odd and blurry:

[image: I Hate You IE]

I've tried obfuscating them as so:

`+44 (<span>0) 1234</span> 567 890`

but Skype still recognises them. I am aware that is a plugin, just wondered if anyone knew of any meta tags or equivalent.

Comment: Who is e**a@o**tme**a.**? Does she approve of you publishing her email address? That Skype plugin sucks bigtime.

Comment: I wouldn't worry, the email is going to be public on the site I'm building for her.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer - [use `&shy;` between numbers](http://www.ambrosite.com/blog/hide-phone-numbers-from-skype-using-the-html-soft-hyphen).

Answer (score 1):

This looks like fun (jQuery):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    window.setTimeout(function() {
        $('.skype_pnh_container').html('');
        $('.skype_pnh_print_container').removeClass('skype_pnh_print_container');
    }, 800);
});
```

Copied from http://www.petefreitag.com/item/751.cfm

Comment: Thanks spender, it doesn't work though? I've delayed the timeout. Maybe Skype have changed their plugin markup. I will borrow the principle though.

* cracks open firebug lite *